# how to draw a semicircle using bezier with variable data?

Tags: swift

How can I draw 2 semicircles in Swift with data stored in variables?
taking the radius and angle stored in the variables, (InRadius, OutRadius and Grades), Any ideas?

here the code for calculate Radius and grade:

```
@IBAction func Calcular(_ sender: Any) {
        
        let a = Double(dmenor.text!)
        let b = Double(DMayor.text!)
        let c = Double(Altura.text!)
        

        if a != nil && b != nil && c != nil{
            

                let h = Double(b! * c!) / (b! - a!)
                let l = Double(sqrt((b! * b! / 4) + (h * h)))
                let ñ = Double(h-c!)
                let i = Double(sqrt((a! * a! / 4) + (ñ * ñ)))
                let g = Double(b! * 180) / (l)

                InRadius.text  = String(format:"%.1f", i)
               OutRadius.text  = String(format:"%.1f", l)
                  Grades.text  = String(format:"%.1f", g)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show what code you've tried so far?

Comment: I have no idea how to do it so I ask for an idea

Comment: Hmm well you'll need [`UIBezierPath`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibezierpath) - here's a tutorial: https://www.appcoda.com/bezier-paths-introduction/

Comment: Thanks, I will read it to understand it, but how to change the values ​​of the radius of a circle with the variables that I have?

Comment: Just pass in your variable to [`addArc(withCenter:radius:startAngle:endAngle:clockwise:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibezierpath/1624367-addarc)'s `radius` argument label

Comment: any code examples?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below code for semicircle
This is the best video I found. You can see his video and download the complete [source code](https://www.letsbuildthatapp.com/course_video?id=2342).

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    // let's start by drawing a circle somehow
    
    let center = view.center
    
    // create my track layer
    let trackLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    
    let circularPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: 100, startAngle: 0, endAngle: CGFloat.pi, clockwise: true)
    trackLayer.path = circularPath.cgPath
    
    trackLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    trackLayer.lineWidth = 10
    trackLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    trackLayer.lineCap = kCALineCapRound
    view.layer.addSublayer(trackLayer) // if you add only this line you will get border only 
    view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer) // If you add only this line you will get half colored circle 

   // If you will add both in addSublayer you will get border and semi colored circle

  }
```

Here's the result. You have to read comments in code it will help you.

[image]

Comment: how can change this value for a variable value:  "center, radius: 100"